# cant create wix setup with embedded c++ redistributable

Tags: wix, wix3

I cant install c++  redistributable using wix. it generate setup but setup do nothing on PC. I cant find any redistributable instalation after my setup.
my wsx:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
```

```
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Merge Id="redistr" Language="1033" SourceFile="..\merge_modules\Microsoft_VC100_CRT_x64.msm" DiskId="1" />
    </Directory>

    <Feature Id="Feature_B" Title="Visual C++ 8.0 Runtime" 
             AllowAdvertise="yes" 

             Level="1">
        <MergeRef Id="redistr" />

    </Feature>

</Product>
```

compilation:
`candle.exe MyMergeModuleSetup.wxs -ext WixUIExtension
light.exe -out demo.msi -b "s:\wix" MyMergeModuleSetup.wixobj -ext WixUIExtension`

output:
`light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE82: This action System64Folder_amd64_VC.1C11561A_11CB_36A7_8A47_D7A042055FA7 has duplicate sequence number 1 in the table InstallExecuteSequence
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE82: This action System64Folder_amd64_VC.1C11561A_11CB_36A7_8A47_D7A042055FA7 has duplicate sequence number 1 in the table InstallUISequence
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE82: This action System64Folder_amd64_VC.1C11561A_11CB_36A7_8A47_D7A042055FA7 has duplicate sequence number 3 in the table AdminExecuteSequence
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE82: This action System64Folder_amd64_VC.1C11561A_11CB_36A7_8A47_D7A042055FA7 has duplicate sequence number 3 in the table AdminUISequence
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE82: This action System64Folder_amd64_VC.1C11561A_11CB_36A7_8A47_D7A042055FA7 has duplicate sequence number 3 in the table AdvtExecuteSequence`

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? This would affect what version of the runtime you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installation, the merge module would not be listed separately in *Programs and Features*. The files/components from the merge module become part of your install, rather than a separate installation.

You can use [**Orca**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557(v=vs.85).aspx) to examine the component and file tables, and verify your install contains components/files for the Visual C++ Redistributable.

Windows Installer will track components that are shared among installs using a [**reference counting mechanism**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369820(v=vs.85).aspx). There are also [**component rules**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370561(v=vs.85).aspx) that must be followed to allow the sharing of components (and for components in general). [**Merge module**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369820(v=vs.85).aspx) are a way to bundle these shared components for inclusion in other installs. The contents of the merge module are included (merged) in the produced installer.

See also [**About Shared Components**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2009/12/21/about-shared-components/)